# Android - Get String Array from another class: A more efficiently code

Tags: java, android

I am facing the following situation: I need a code that is able to autocomplete a given AutoCompleteTextView (called:city) when the user types at least two characters in another AutoCompleteTextView (called state). The code I am using is as follows:

**Main.java**

```
final String[] arrayEmpty = {""};
                    final EditText State = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditState);
                    State.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
                    {
                        if (!hasFocus) {

                            if(State.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kerala")) {

                                listCities newClassObj = new listCities(); 
                                String [] Cities = newClassObj.list_Kerala();
                                AutoCompleteTextView StatesTextView;
                                ArrayAdapter<String> StatesAdapter;
                                StatesTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditCities);
                                StatesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cities);
                                StatesTextView.setThreshold(2); 
                                StatesTextView.setAdapter(StatesAdapter);

                            } else  if(State.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Deli")) {

                                listCities newClassObj = new listCities(); 
                                String [] Cities = newClassObj.list_Deli();
                                AutoCompleteTextView StatesTextView;
                                ArrayAdapter<String> StatesAdapter;
                                StatesTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditCities);
                                StatesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cities);
                                StatesTextView.setThreshold(2); 
                                StatesTextView.setAdapter(StatesAdapter);
        }

            [ more lot of states and cityes ... ]

            else { //Last Else clear the array
    AutoCompleteTextView statesTextView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> statesAdapter;
    statesTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditCities);
    statesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayEmpty);
    StatesTextView.setThreshold(2); 
    StatesTextView.setAdapter(StatesAdapter);
     }
     }

     }
                });
```

**ListCities Class:**

```
class ListCities {
    //Cities off Kerala
    private String [] Kerala = {
            "Cochim", "Calecute", "MORE cities"
    };

    public String[] list_Kerala() {
        return Kerala.clone();
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Cities of Deli
    private String [] Deli = {
            "Gurgaon", "Ghaziabad", "Lot more Cities"
    };

    public String[] list_Deli() {
        return Deli.clone();
    }
```

The code does what I need. However, I'd like to find a way to make it more efficient, with a smaller code maybe. Can someone help me?

Comment: There's a lot of redundant variables being created in your if-else statement. perhaps refactoring that to remove the redundancy is a good step. It may not optimise your code but it would make it easier to read and reduce the number of lines it's taking up.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. But I'm a beginner on Android, how can I reduce all this redundancy? Thaks in advance.

Comment: How many cases are you having to program for (i.e. how many elseif's will there be)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring the code should make it easier for you to write out all the cases and minimise repetition when you do so. I'd recommend using a more "genericly" named TextView and ArrayAdapter that you can use them for all of the cases without getting confused about what they do.

```
final String[] arrayEmpty = {""};
final EditText State = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditState);
State.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            listCities newClassObj = new listCities();
            AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
            String [] Cities;

            if(State.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kerala")) {
                Cities = newClassObj.list_Kerala();
                autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditCities);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cities);
            }
            else if(State.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Deli")) {
                Cities = newClassObj.list_Deli();
                autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditCities);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cities);
            }
            else { //Last Else clear the array
                autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditBairro);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DenunciaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayEmpty);
            }

            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(2);
        }
    }
});
```

Another thing you could possibly consider (that I'm not 100% sure about) is creating an object which handles instantiating and managing all of these variables for you. Which would reduce the if-elseif-else down to something like

```
Cities[] cities;
if(State.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kerala"))
{
    cities = new City("Kerala");
}
else if() // etc.
```

Comment: I also recommend the code review stack exchange. It's probably a more appropriate place for questions like this one.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/